# Plotting function on matplot lib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the function f(x) with matplotlib but I am not getting the graph as expected. The code is plotting just a blue horizontal line and I don't understand why.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)
f_x = (x+3)/(x-5)

plt.axhline(y=0, color="black")
plt.axhline(y=1.0, color="black", linestyle="--")
plt.axvline(x=5,color="grey", linestyle="--")
plt.axvline(color="black")
plt.plot(f_x, linewidth=2, label=r"$f(x) = \frac{x+3}{x-5}$")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.ylim(-10,10)
plt.xlim(-10,10)
plt.legend(fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your code lies in the way you're plotting the function. Instead of using plt.plot(f_x, ...), you should use plt.plot(x, f_x, ...), as you need to provide the x-values along with the corresponding y-values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the function
def f(x):
    return (x + 3) / (x - 5)

# Generate x values
x = np.linspace(-100, 100, 100)

# Calculate corresponding y values using the function
f_x = f(x)

# Plot the function
plt.axhline(y=0, color="black")
plt.axhline(y=1.0, color="black", linestyle="--")
plt.axvline(x=5, color="grey", linestyle="--")
plt.axvline(color="black")
plt.plot(x, f_x, linewidth=2, label=r"$f(x) = \frac{x+3}{x-5}$")
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.ylim(-10, 10)
plt.xlim(-10, 10)
plt.legend(fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

Now, the function f(x) is properly plotted with the x-values generated using np.linspace.

The result :

[image]

Comment: thanks for the input! There is still a problem because the function for x=5- should go to -inf

Comment: 1. To explain further, when you do `plt.plot(f_x)` and don't provide an `x`, matplotlib will plot the function against `range(len(f_x))` (i.e. against the index). If you remove the limits you will see that. 2. Regarding the infinity "issue", your x discretization doesn't have the value 5 (the closest is 5.05050505), so you only have finite numbers. And even if you did have 5, I don't think matplotlib plots infinity; it will just leave that point out.